# Sending an image over a socket as bytes

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I want to send a screenshot of the server to the client, in order to do this, I want to send the image as bytes, and split it to parts, each part in length of 1024.

First, the program does multiple things, it sends also files, the time etc.. so the client needs to tell the server he/(it)? wants an image so he first sends 'Img', then the server returns 'Img' back, when the client receives the 'Img' back, he starts listening to all the parts and the server starts sending all the parts, when the last part is sent, the server sends 'Sent'.

My code so far: **Client.py:**

```
def listen_for_image():
    bytes_data = socket_con.recv(1024)
    part = bytes_data
    i = 1
    print("Part #", str(i))
    while part.decode() != 'Sent':
        part = socket_con.recv(1024)
        bytes_data += part
        i += 1
        print("Part #", str(i))
    return bytes_data


    socket_con.send('Img')
    data_back = socket_con.recv(1024)
    if data_back.decode() == 'Img':
        bytes_full_data = listen_for_image()
        img = Image.frombytes('RGB', (1366, 768), bytes_full_data)
        img.save('newimg.jpg')
```

**Server.py:**

```
def send_screen_shot():
    con.send('Img'.encode())
    image = ImageGrab.grab()
    start = 0
    end = 1024
    while end < len(image.tobytes()):
        con.send(image.tobytes()[start:end])
        start = end + 1
        end += 1024
    con.send("Sent".encode())


if con.recv(1024).decode() == 'Img':
        send_screen_shot()
```

Note that my program does more so this is not the full code but only the parts needed, if you need something else, just ask :)

The problem with my code is that on client side I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/untitled/client.py", line 33, in <module>
    bytes_full_data = listen_for_image()
  File "C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/untitled/client.py", line 14, in listen_for_image
    while part.decode() != 'Sent':
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

**EDIT:**
I tried switching the encoder in order to solve this problem, for example:

**Client.py:**

```
def listen_for_image():
    bytes_data = socket_con.recv(1024)
    part = bytes_data
    i = 1
    print("Part #", str(i))
    while part.decode('ISO-8859-1') != 'Sent':
        part = socket_con.recv(1024)
        bytes_data += part
        i += 1
        print("Part #", str(i))
    return bytes_data
```

**Server.py:**

```
def send_screen_shot():
    con.send('Img'.encode())
    image = ImageGrab.grab()
    start = 0
    end = 1024
    while end < len(image.tobytes()):
        con.send(image.tobytes(encoder_name='ISO-8859-1')[start:end])
        start = end + 1
        end += 1024
    con.send("Sent".encode('ISO-8859-1'))
```

But then I get an error on server side:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 437, in _getencoder
    encoder = getattr(core, encoder_name + "_encoder")
AttributeError: module 'PIL._imaging' has no attribute 'ISO-8859-2_encoder'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/untitled/server.py", line 42, in <module>
    send_screen_shot()
  File "C:/Users/dodob/PycharmProjects/untitled/server.py", line 19, in send_screen_shot
    con.send(image.tobytes(encoder_name='ISO-8859-2')[start:end])
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 681, in tobytes
    e = _getencoder(self.mode, encoder_name, args)
  File "C:\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 441, in _getencoder
    raise IOError("encoder %s not available" % encoder_name)
OSError: encoder ISO-8859-2 not available
```

And the client keeps running like this:

```
...
Part # 2376824
Part # 2376825
Part # 2376826
Part # 2376827
Part # 2376828
Part # 2376829
Part # 2376830
Part # 2376831
Part # 2376832
Part # 2376833
Part # 2376834
...
```

I think this error is caused because there is no such encoder but I tried multiple ones and it happens every time.. but anyway, I don't know why the client keeps running, the `recv` function should stop until it receives something, and here it is running forever.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
while part != b'Sent':
```

and the same style throughout. Your problem is that you're trying to decode the binary data in the image as well, text. It's not. And you don't need to convert it to text to compare against your known values - you just use *bytes* as your known values.

Also you want to change this:

```
while end < len(image.tobytes()):
    con.send(image.tobytes(encoder_name='ISO-8859-1')[start:end])
    start = end + 1
    end += 1024
con.send("Sent".encode('ISO-8859-1'))
```

To this:

```
img_bytes = image.tobytes()
while end < len(img_bytes):
    con.send(img_bytes[start:end])
    start = end + 1
    end += 1024
con.send("Sent".encode())
```

That's going to save you re-converting the image to bytes every time. If your image is 1024000 bytes large, you'd call that function **2,000** times. Don't do that. It may not be a serious problem, as the network transfer is a few orders of magnitude slower, but you can still shave anywhere from tenths to full seconds off, depending on the size of your image(s).

Oh, and another thing:

```
while part and part != b'Sent':
    part = socket_con.recv(1024)
    bytes_data += part
    i += 1
    print("Part #", str(i))
```

This way if the socket closes you'll actually exit your loop. When a socket is closed it's guaranteed that `.recv` will return an empty string (of bytes). This evaluates to `False`, so if you receive *no data* then it will kick out of this loop.

Comment: That's great, this part works now, it raised another error but I will work in order to solve it !

Comment: Emm , A simple question - if the bytes length for example is 4608, I need to send it from 0 to 4608 including both? meaning 0(including) - 1024, 1025 - 2048, 2049 - 3072, 3073 - 4096, 4097 - 4608(including)

Comment: I'm slightly confused by what you're asking. I think you have enough rep to come [talk in the python room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python).

Answer (score 0):

If you send the image over the socket like this, you'll notice that there are some bytes remaining that have not been sent.
In order to avoid that, replace

```
start = end + 1
```

with

```
start = end
```